# Regex validate and correct telephone number

Tags: php, regex

At the moment I am validating and correcting given Telephone numbers with this version of code:

```
function validateTelephoneNumber($parameters){
    
    $validTel = "<^((\\+|00)[1-9]\\d{0,3}|0 ?[1-9]|\\(00? ?[1-9][\\d ]*\\))[\\d\\-/ ]*$>";

    $telNumber = $parameters;

    if (preg_match($validTel, $telNumber)) {
        $telNumber = preg_replace("<^\\+>", "00", $telNumber);
        $telNumber = preg_replace("<\\D+>", "", $telNumber);
    }
    return $telNumber;
}
```

what I want to get is:

```
|               input               |           return value            |     comment (only info)     |
|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------|
| 0043/2342/213412-1234             | +4323422134121234                 |                             |
| +43 234 2312341234 12             | +43234231234123412                |                             |
| 07234/32434                       | +43723432434                      |if no country prefix -> +43  |
| (0677)32423434                    | +4367732423434                    |if no country prefix -> +43  |
| 0049 171 12341234                 | +4917112341234                    |                             |
| 0031 9872 12341234                | +31987212341234                   |                             |
| 0043(07234)1234-1234              | +43723412341234                   |remove 0 in local prefix     |
```

Can you help? Thanks

Comment: What is the rule that tells you that `43` in `0043/2342/213412-1234` is a country code but `72` in `07234/32434` is not a country code?

Comment: In future please display data used in examples in a form that makes it easy for readers to cut-and-paste to test their answers. Here only the first column of your table is needed for that. Separating that from the rest is not difficult it would have been easier if you had presented the first column alone and then shown the desired results separately.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion of the telephone number (after validation) can be done in three steps.

**Step 1: replace leading zeros with `"43"` if the there is no country code.**

I assume there is no country code if the string contains exactly one forward slash or begins with a left parenthesis. To add the defautlt country code we can replaces matches of the following regular expression with `"43"`.

```
^(?:\(0*|0*(?=\d+\/\d+$))
```

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/j1DGaw/4/). PHP's regex engine performs the following operations:

```
^              : assert beginning of string
(?:            : begin non-capture group
  \(0*         : match '(' followed by 0+ zeroes
  |            : or
  0*           : match 0+ zeros
  (?=          : begin positive lookahead
    \d+\/\d+   : match 1+ digits, '/', 0+ digits
    $          : assert end of string  
  )            : end positive lookahead
)              : end non-capture group
```

This will convert the strings

```
0043/2342/213412-1234
+43234 2312341234 12
07234/32434
(0677)32423434
0049 171 12341234
0031 9872 12341234
0043(07234)1234-1234
```

to

```
0043/2342/213412-1234
+43234 2312341234 12
437234/32434
43677)32423434
0049 171 12341234
0031 9872 12341234
0043(07234)1234-1234
```

**Step 2: remove unwanted characters**

For this step we replace matches of the following regular expression with empty strings.

```
^0+|[ +\/()-]
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/j1DGaw/3/). PHP's regex engine performs the following operations:

```
^          : assert beginning of string
0+         : match 1+ zeroes
|          : or
[ +\/()-]  : match one character in the character class
```

This will convert the strings obtained in Step 1 to the following.

```
4323422134121234
43234231234123412
43723432434
4367732423434
4917112341234
31987212341234
430723412341234
```

**Step 3: Add `'+'` to the beginning of the string**

This is most easily done with a PHP statement, producing the following strings.

```
+4323422134121234
+43234231234123412
+43723432434
+4367732423434
+4917112341234
+31987212341234
+430723412341234
```

Comment: @cary-swoeland yea thats a good idea but, follwoing numbers are not corrected as wished.. 0049 171 12341234, 0031 9872 12341234, 0043(07234)1234-1234

Comment: I misunderstood one aspect of the question. I have revised my answer. Note that in my "Step 1" my assumption about how one determines if a string does not contain a country code may be incorrect, as the criterion is not made clear in the question.

Comment: @cary_swoveland Hy,
I tried following php code...:
```
function validateTelephoneNumber($parameters){
 
 $validTel = "([\d\(][\(\)\s\.\-\d]{4,}\d)";

 $telNumber = $parameters;

 if (preg_match($validTel, $telNumber)) {
  $telNumber = preg_replace("^(?:\(0*|0*(?=\d+\/\d+$))", "43", $telNumber);
  $telNumber = preg_replace("^0+|[ +\/()-]", "", $telNumber);
  $telNumber = '+' . $telNumber;
 }
 return $telNumber;
}
``` but it doesn't work as wished.

Comment: I don't know PHP, so I can't help you with that, but perhaps another reader can.